# Add a lookup fild by the bottom Click, not from Adding Item

Tags: development

Hello how to add to the value by bottom click not from the Adding Item. Only from code:

```
          protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                using (SPWeb witryna = SPContext.Current.Web)
                {
                    SPListItemCollection listItems = witryna.Lists["Szczegoly"].Items;

                    SPListItem item = listItems.Add();
                    item["Kontrakt"] = TextBox1.Text;
                    item["Pracownik"] = TextBox2.Text;
                    item["Dzien"] = TextBox3.Text;
                    item["Procenty"] = TextBox4.Text;
                    item.Update();
                }
            }
```

Here is My code. How can I choise and add a Value to `item["Procenty"] = TextBox4.Text;` When I debug it show me that Value is no-writable.

Comment: I done this Thanks to Per Per Jakobsen:) http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/37681/how-do-i-update-a-lookup-column-from-a-dropdownlist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a SPFieldLookupValue object,

```
SPFieldLookupValue splkup=new SPFieldLookupValue(TextBox4.Text);
item["Procenty"] = splkup;
```

Comment: But now it's tells me that the value is out of range.

Comment: If I put this `SPFieldLookupValue splkup = new SPFieldLookupValue(5, "5/8");` it show me 3/8 and adding

Comment: It's a good way, but something i Schould get value

Answer (score 0):

What's the internal name of this field? Is it custom?

Assuming that *item["Procenty"]* is the same as *item["PercentComplete"]* you could set it with something like this (Note that TextBox.Text returns a string)

```
//Set item to 10% completet
item["PercentComplete"] = .10;
```

Comment: But the percent, are in "1/8", "2/8" .... "8/8" values

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean. You want to read the value from a TextBox which only allows "1/8" steps? Can't you just calculate the new value like 1/8=1:8=0.125 which would be 12.5%.

Comment: Now in percent, only in String Values

Comment: You only have the strings 1/8, 2/8,... 8/8? Why don't you just display them that way then? Could you explain what excactly you're trying to do? Maybe in another questions, because the original question was just why you couldn't write to item["Procenty"].

Comment: I want to add by boton Click Values element by element.

Comment: Yes sure, but why do you only have values like 1/8 but display them as percentage? Why don't you just use and display normal percentage? Or a dropdown if you just have 8 values anyway?